Bug appeared after upgrading from 2022.3.30 to 2022.3.53 with plugins in Unity. launcher:mapReleaseSourceSePaths. launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath
After Unity update, bugs related to plugins available on project started appearing in Android builds
WHAT I TRIED TO DO
I tried making an empty project and installing 2 pairs of different plugin packages, but I still end up with the same error.
Also I tried to change external dependency manager settings and project settings and check google for this problem. I couldn't find anything
HOW YOU CAN REPRODUCE IT
How can it be reproduced in Unity:

Download the new version and create empty project

Enable the build on Android

Download Firebase Analytics plugin
If you do the build now, no error will occur

Download Google Play Games plugin (for example)
After that the error will appear


image of exception

So bug report it to unity, not us.  It has a built in bug report tool after all.
